# Accessing different array values from inside a multi-dimentional array using a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have created an array using a foreach loop and the result loops like this:

```
array(8) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["shortdesc"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#63 (1) {...}
        ["longdesc"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#58 (1) {...} 
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#64 (1) {...} 
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        ["shortdesc"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#67 (1) {...} 
        ["longdesc"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#62 (1) {...} 
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#68 (1) {...} 
    }  
    (...)
}
```

Using this array and a foreach below:

```
foreach ($optionsArray as $innerArray) {
  foreach ($innerArray as $value) {
    echo "<li>$value</li>";
  } 
}
```

I can echo out all of the content of the array, but I want to be able to assign the different array parts to variables.

So:

```
foreach ($optionsArray as $innerArray) {
  foreach ($innerArray as $value) {
    echo "<li>$value->price $value->longdesc</li>";
  } 
}
```

I know $value is not an object, but how can I do what I am looking for? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use the inner `foreach` loop?

Comment: I think there is something going wrong when you create the array. I am wondering why the data is splitted into different objects. Can you show the code where you create this array?

Comment: Strictly spoken `$value` is an object of type **SimpleXMLElement**, so it is an object. It's just that when used inside strings or with echo etc. it automatically casts to string. Just FYI. And you might benefit by reading over this SimpleXML Tutorial in the PHP manual: [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) - It covers what you asked about and some more good hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No need to use **innerArray**  foreach loop ,Just try given below code:

```
foreach ($optionsArray as $innerArray) 
{
  echo $innerArray['price']."<br>";
  echo $innerArray['longdesc']."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
foreach ($optionsArray as $innerArray) {
   $object = (object) $innerArray;
   echo $object->price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($optionsArray as $innerArray) 
{
    echo "<li>" . $innerArray['price'] . " " . $innerArray['longdesc'] . "</li>";
}
```